# Inequality for Sum of Square Roots

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are two distinct sequences of positive numbers, each of which adds up to 1.  Is it necessarily the case that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{x_ny_n}<1$?

Comment: Two answers using AM-GM. Cauchy–Schwarz is also applicable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by AM-GM. Choose any index $k$ where $x_k \ne y_k$ and notice that

$$\sqrt{x_k y_k} < \frac{x_k + y_k}{2}$$

Comment: NICE! This makes it even valid for non-negative and finite DISTINCT sequences.